# Are the prime numbers prime in the domain of integers?

Tags: abstract-algebra

> An element $p$ of a domain $R$ is prime when $p$ is not zero or a unit, and $p \setminus ab$ implies $p\setminus a$ or $p\setminus b$ (equivalently $ab\in Rp$ implies $a \in Rp$ or $b\in Rp$). An element $q$ of a domain $R$ is *irreducible* when $q$ is not zero or a unit, and $q = ab$ implies that $a$ is a unit or $b$ is a unit.

Are the prime numbers prime in the domain of integers? And are the prime numbers irreducible?

Comment: Yes, prime numbers are prime in the ring $\Bbb Z$. Since this ring is a PID, prime and irreducible is the same (see abstract algebra), i.e., $x\in \Bbb Z$ is prime iff it is irreducible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes to both questions. Use the facts from basic number theory that $\pm 1$ are the only invertible integers and that an integer other than $\pm 1$ can be expressed uniquely as $\pm$ the product of distinct primes each raised to a power that is a positive integer and both results follow easily.

Answer (score 1):

Prime numbers are both prime and irreducible in the domain of integers.

They are irreducible by definition.

To prove that they are prime, one recalls the Euclidean algorithm for finding GCD of two integers (which at the same time proves that any two integers have a unique, up to equivalence, GCD, without referring to prime decomposition). From Euclidean algorithm it also follows that, if $d=\gcd(a,b)$ for two numbers $a,b\in\mathbb Z$, then there are integers $u,v\in\mathbb Z$ such that $d=ua+vb$. (Bezout's property.)

Now, imagine $p$ is prime in the ordinary sense, meaning that it is irreducible. Suppose $p|ab$, and let $d=\gcd(p,a)$, $d=up+va$. Because $d|p$, it follows (from irreducibility) that either $d$ is a unit or $d$ is equivalent to $p$, so we can, by multiplying $d,u,v$ by a unit, reduce this to the case where $d=1$ or $d=p$.

- If $d=1$, then $1=up+va$, i.e. $b=upb+vab$, and the right side is divisible by $p$, so $p|b$.
- If $d=p$, with $d=\gcd(p,a)|a$ we have $p|a$.

In a general integral domain $R$, being prime implies being irreducible. The opposite implication is valid whenever $R$ is an *Euclidean domain* (i.e. it allows for Euclidean algorithm in a sense), or if it is a *principal ideal domain* (i.e. every ideal is *principal* - generated by a single element), or is a *Bezout domain* (i.e. the sum of every two principal ideals is a principal ideal) - the proof being just the same as in the case of $\mathbb Z$.